# Is it possible to put vim comments in lines that include `iabbrev`

Tags: comments, abbreviations

Is it possible to put vim comments in lines that include `iabbrev`, as in:

```
iabbrev hte the " common typo
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in [`:help 40.1`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_40.txt.html#40.1) (`SPECIAL CHARACTERS`):

```
It is not possible to put a comment directly after a mapping, because the "
character is considered to be part of the mapping.  You can use |", this
starts a new, empty command with a comment.  Example: 

        :map <Space> W|     " Use spacebar to move forward a word
```

So, you can use `|` in order to indicate the end of the abbreviation/mapping:

```
iabbrev hte the| " common typo
```

Comment: Do I have to put the vertical bar `|` right after the abbreviation?

Comment: Yes. Try copying the last line of the answer into your Vim command line.